# Fredhopper.biz.log performance analyzer

Tags: fredhopper, performance

When we try to debug query instance performance with Fredhopper support, they allways require fredhopper.biz.log and based on it they provide some statistics from it which looks like this:
[image]

Has anyone heard, or developed such a tool (or maybe got it from support)?
It looks like a nice performance tool to have.

Comment: This looks like it's a general tool for any Fredhopper setup? It might be worth checking with [Fredhopper Support or on the Fredhopper Knowledge Base](https://www.fredhopper.com/support.html). You could also check with SDL Support, but we'd end up going through a similar channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have contacted Fredhopper customer support and they have provided me with the scripts: 
log-analyzer.pl and  log-analyzer.py.
If you have the similar request, please feel free to contact them and they should provide it to you.